# Bot Follow up prompts do not work on IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, bots, azure-qna-maker

I have implemented a bot (4.0) that uses QnA maker follow up prompts feature. The bot is embedded within a web page via direct line channel and my web page is using `webchat-es5.js` to make it compatible with IE11. However when the answer from QnA maker has follow up prompt, the page actually hangs in IE11 because `webchat-es5.js` throws an error

```
uncaught at anonymous TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)_6.si6vipw8wb1'"
```

Upon debugging that js I found out that if I skip below line in script then it works.
`var v=(0,i.default)(t.children,1)[0]`

Has anyone come across this problem? Any help is appreciated. The follow up feature works fine in Chrome, Edge and Firefox. The issue exists only in IE11.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the webchat-es5.js I would recommended heading over to the Bot Framework-Webchat [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) and posting it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is an issue related to the webchat, you could check this [similar thread](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2222), and the developer was investigating the cause and will fix it in the latest release.

As a temporary workaround, you could try to use the browser-polyfill from babel@5.6. Just add this to your index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```